# How to generate points within rectangle, at random locations and without overlap?

Tags: python

I have an image with width: 1980 and height: 1080.
Ultimately, I want to place various shapes within the image, but at random locations and in such a way that they do not overlap. The 0,0 coordinates of the image are in the center.

Before rendering the shapes into the image (I don't need help with this), I need to write an algorithm to generate the XY points/locations. I want to be able to specify the minimum distance any given point is allowed to get to any other points.

How can do this?

All I have been able to do, is to generate points at equally spaced locations and then add a bit of randomness to each point. But this is not ideal, because it means points just vary within some 'cell' within a grid, and if the randomness value is too high, they will appear outside of the rectangle. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from random import randrange

def is_square(integer):
    root = np.sqrt(integer)
    return integer == int(root + 0.5) ** 2

def perfect_sqr(n):
    nextN = np.floor(np.sqrt(n)) + 1
    return int(nextN * nextN)

def generate_cells(width = 1920, height = 1080, n = 9, show_plot=False):

    # If the number is not a perfect square, we need to find the next number which is
    # so that we can get the root N, which will be used to determine the number of rows/columns
    if not is_square(n):
        n = perfect_sqr(n)
    N = np.sqrt(n)

    # generate x and y lists, where each represents an array of points evenly spaced between 0 and the width/height
    x = np.array(list(range(0, width, int(width/N))))
    y = np.array(list(range(0, height, int(height/N))))

    # center the points within each 'cell'
    x_centered = x+int(width/N)/2
    y_centered = y+int(height/N)/2

    x_centered = [a+randrange(50) for a in x_centered]
    y_centered = [a+randrange(50) for a in y_centered]

    # generate a grid with the points
    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x_centered, y_centered)

    if(show_plot):
        plt.scatter(xv,yv)
        plt.gca().add_patch(Rectangle((0,0),width, height,edgecolor='red', facecolor='none', lw=1))
        plt.show()

    # convert the arrays to 1D
    xx = xv.flatten()
    yy = yv.flatten()

    # Merge them side-by-side
    zips = zip(xx, yy)

    # convert to set of points/tuples and return
    return set(zips)


coords = generate_cells(width=1920, height=1080, n=15, show_plot=True)
print(coords)
```

Comment: Clearly there is more going on here than creating a set of random numbers within an x & y range with a specified spacing.  What is the purpose of computing perfect square?  How does this factor into your question?

Comment: @itprorh66 my code generates a grid, where each cell may or may not have an object within it, so the perfect square is needed in order to determine if there are enough cells, or whether we need to generate more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you simply want to randomly define non-overlapping coordinates within the confines of a maximum image size subject to not having images overlap, this might be a good solution.

```
import numpy as np 
def locateImages(field_height: int, field_width: int, min_sep: int, points: int)-> np.array:
    h_range = np.array(range(min_sep//2, field_height - (min_sep//2), min_sep))
    w_range = np.array(range(min_sep//2, field_width-(min_sep//2), min_sep))
    mx_len = max(len(h_range), len(w_range))
    if len(h_range) < mx_len:
        xtra = np.random.choice(h_range, mx_len - len(h_range))
        h_range = np.append(h_range, xtra)
    if len(w_range) < mx_len:
        xtra = np.random.choice(w_range, mx_len - len(w_range))
        w_range = np.append(w_range, xtra)
    h_points = np.random.choice(h_range, points, replace=False)
    w_points = np.random.choice(w_range, points, replace=False)
    return np.concatenate((np.vstack(h_points), np.vstack(w_points)), axis= 1)
```

Then given:
field_height = the vertical coordinate of the Image space
field_width = the maximum horizontal coordinate of the Image space
min_sep = the minimum spacing between images
points = number of coordinates to be selected

Then:
`locateImages(15, 8, 2, 5)` will yield:

```
array([[13,  1],
       [ 7,  3],
       [ 1,  5],
       [ 5,  5],
       [11,  5]])
```

Render the output:

```
points = locateImages(1080, 1920, 100, 15)
x,y= zip(*points)
plt.scatter(x,x)
plt.gca().add_patch(Rectangle((0,0),1920, 1080,edgecolor='red', facecolor='none', lw=1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. All it does is place some points along a vector. Check my edit to your code (renders the output), and compare the output of your code with mine. You will see what I mean.

Comment: I tried your code and see the plot you reference, but I am confused.  In the example I ran, I ended up with 15 x and 15 y points, which is consistent with the call to locateImages, yet the resulting plot only shows 9 points.  In addition, my x coordinates extend to a max of 950 and y coord go to 1750, yet the plot area seem to extend to 900 in x direction and 900 in y direction.  Thus all locations are not being plotted.